# Characters of simply connected semsimple algebraic groups over local fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, local-fields

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then by definition $G$ admits no non-trivial *algebraic* characters, i.e. homomorphisms $G \to \mathbb{G}_m$.

However, it is quite possible that $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ admits *topological* characters. E.g. take $G=\mathrm{PGL}_n$ and consider the composition
$$\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to \mathbb{Q}_p^*/\mathbb{Q}_p^{*n} \to S^1, \quad g \mapsto \chi(\det(g)),$$
where $\chi: \mathbb{Q}_p^*/\mathbb{Q}_p^{*n} \to S^1$ is some character.

In this special case $G$ is adjoint, however. I can also do similar constructions for other adjoint groups. So I'm wondering whether this can also happen for simply connected $G$.

> Let $G$ be a simply connected semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is any continuous homomorphism
>   $$G(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to S^1$$
>   trivial?

Comment: What do you mean by $g\mapsto \text{det}(g)$?  For every linear representation that I can think of, the image of $\textbf{PGL}_n$ is contained in $\textbf{SL}_M$.

Comment: Are you taking $n=p-1$, so that the reduction of the determinant on $\textbf{GL}_{p-1}$ is a well-defined homomorphism  $\textbf{PGL}_{p-1}(\mathbb{Z}_p) \to \mathbb{F}_p^\times$?  If so, how do you extend this to $\textbf{PGL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

Comment: For PGL_n, det takes values in H^1(k,mu_n)=k*/(k*)^n. But det is surjective and its target admits nontrivial homomorphisms to the circle when k is the p-adics so you've still got your topological character.

Comment: @Jason and Peter: Yes sorry, I forgot to compose det with a character; I have changed the statement.

Comment: @YCor: Don't you mean that the answer to my question is in fact "yes"? Which book of Margulis are you referring to?

Comment: A version of @YCor's comment: Let $G$ be a simply connected absolutely simple $k$-group, where $k$ is a nonarchimedean local field (a $p$-adic field or the field of rational functions in one variable over a finite field). Assume that $G$ is isotropic (i.e., not isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(1,D)$ of a central division algebra $D$ over $k$). Then any nontrivial normal subgroup of $G(k)$ is central, hence finite. For a proof see the book by Platonov and Rapinchuk. Therefore, $G(k)$ admits no nontrivial homomorphisms into abelian groups.

Comment: @Mikhail: Thanks. The result you state has many assumptions. Are you implying that the answer to my question is "no" in general? E.g. what happens for the group $\mathrm{SL}_1(D)$?

Comment: @YCor: Do you know a precise reference? I looked at Platonov-Rapinchuk's book, but I only found the weaker statement mentioned by Mikhail.

Comment: For $G=SL(1,D)$ the group $G(k)$ is compact, hence profinite, hence it has a lot of finite quotients.

Comment: You're right. The absolute simplicity is not important, but the isotropic assumption is essential in the argument, which uses generation by unipotents. (As Mikhail, in the anisotropic case I'm not aware of an example with nontrivial finite abelian quotient.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I have written in a comment, the answer is YES (any abstract homomorphism into an abelian group is trivial) when $G$ is an *isotropic*, simply connected, simple algebraic group over a nonarchmedean local field $k$. For a proof see the book by Platonov and Rapinchuk, Section 7.2, Theorems 7.1 and 7.6.
Note that any simply connected *anisotropic* simple group is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(1,D)$, where $D$ is a central simple algebra over a finite separable extension $K$ of $k$.

However, the answer is NO when $k=\mathbb{Q}_2$,
$G=\mathrm{SL}(1,D)$,  and $D$ is the quaternion division algebra over $k$. 
EDIT of 18.11.2018: 
As Arkandias explains in his comments below, for the group $G=\mathrm{SL}(1,D)$ as above, it follows from the Corollary to Theorem 21 of Carl Riehm's paper [The norm 1 group of a p-adic division algebra](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373336?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)
that the abelianization $G^{\rm ab}:=G/[G,G]$ is a group of order 3. Since the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is open and hence, closed in $G$, we see that $G$  admits a non-trivial continuous homomorphism to $S^1$.

Comment: This example seems to contradict the Corollary to Theorem 21 in Riehm "The norm 1 group of a $p$-adic division algebra", which implies that the abelianization of $\mathrm{SL}(1,D)$ has order $q+1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Arkandias: In Theorem 21 Riehm assumes that $D$ is not a dyadic quaternion algebra.

Comment: Yes, but the Corollary includes that case (see just above the statement, and most of the proof is about the dyadic quaternion algebra case).

Comment: @Arkandias: Could you please explain how the corollary to Theorem 21 implies that the abelianization of ${\rm SL}(1,D)$ has order $q+1$?

Comment: @Arkandias: Do I understand correctly that in our case $q=2$, so $q+1=3$ ?

Comment: $k$ is a $p$-adic field with ring of integers $\mathfrak{o}$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, $A$ is a central division algebra over $k$ with ring of integers $\mathfrak{D}$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{P}$. The corollary claims that the commutator of $G_0 := \mathrm{SL}(1,A)$ is the congruence subgroup $H_1$ consisting of those elements $g \in G_0$ which are $\equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{P}$. So the abelianization is isomorphic to $G_0/H_1$, which in turn is isomorphic to the norm $1$ subgroup of the field extension $\mathfrak{D}/\mathfrak{P}$ of $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Finally, this subgroup has cardinal $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ where $n^2$ is the dimension of $A$ over $k$. So in your case ($k=\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $A$ is the quaternion algebra), the order of $G_0/H_1$ should be $3$ according to this corollary, so in particular there should not be any morphism into $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Yet, I do not see anything wrong with your construction...

Comment: @Arkandias: The maps $G(k)\to\mathbb{Z}_2/2\mathbb{Z}_2$ that I constructed is not a homomorphism! I will edit my answer tomorrow.